# Different result of application in different emulator

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an android application that uses Google map api v2 , It work well in Galaxy S3 , but not in Samsung Galaxy young , even if I use Target 4.2 ..
In general I don't have the same result in both physical device ..Why ?

Comment: What's the problem? What result do you expect and what is happening? Please explain the problems you are facing and provide images if possible.

Comment: 1- in galaxy S3 , I can see the map but in in Galaxy young i have an error  
2- I can get the tweets in S3 but not in Galaxy Young

Comment: 1- What error do you get? 
2- What tweets are you talking about? Please provide more information by editing the question. Show us the code that you have written.